# Fitting triangles to a plane

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Given a triangle with three vertex angles α, β and γ, and with unlimited scaling, rotation, reflection  and translation, can you always fit the triangle to a plane so that all 3 vertices fall onto integer coordinates?

Been scratching my head at this for quite a while now. If this can be disproven, can we fit these triangles into higher dimension coordinates similarly (unlimited transformation given vertex angles stay the same, all coordinates are integers)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the triangle with sides $3, 3, \pi$. After scaling it's sides are $3x, 3x, \pi x$. In some coordinate system all 3 vertices fall onto integer coordinates, hence by Pythagorean theorem their squares are sums of squares of integers. Thus $(3x)^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and  $(3 \pi x)^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence $\frac{(3\pi x)^2}{(3x)^2} \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\pi^2$ is rational. Hence $\pi$ is an algebraic number. We got a contradiction.

This solution works not only in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but in $\mathbb{R}^d$ also.